# `Coordinate` of the square angle of `(A)-|(B)`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to have `coordinate` of the square angle on the line `(A)-|(B)` without using the coordinates of A nor B.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,4) ;
\coordinate (B) at (5,3) ;

\draw (A)-|(B) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `(A -| B)` to obtain the desired coordinate:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,4) ;
\coordinate (B) at (5,3) ;

\draw (A)-|(B) ;

\coordinate (X) at (A -| B);
\node [red] at (X) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I sully and uselessly tried `((A) -| (B))`. Thank you !

Comment: @Tarass: Yep, me too. I still do that and have to figure out why every time. Not sure why both styles don't work.